# Java : Determine if String is an URL(without www or http), take its screenshot

Tags: java, spring, image-processing, phantomjs

I am working on a Spring-MVC webapplication in which we are trying to get a screenshot of an URL. Currently I am using PhantomJS for that task, but it's too slow(>10seconds). Also, the URL's have to be with http/https and www for detecting that it's an URL. As this is a chat application, there can be simple URL's which users add like `helloworld.com`. Any help would be nice. Thank you.

Code:

```
 String[] words = message.split(" ");
                for( String item : words ){
                     boolean val = ResourceUtils.isUrl(item);
                    if(val){
                        urlIdentifier = calcUrl(item);
                        break;
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Url false is "+item);
                    }
                }

                if(urlIdentifier!=null){
                    replies.setPreviewIdentifier(urlIdentifier);
                    input.put("preview_identifier",urlIdentifier);
                }
```

Method to calculate screenshot :

```
   private String calcUrl(String website){
        try {
            String identifier = String.valueOf(new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32));
            String previewLocation = msg + "chatthumbs/" + identifier ;

            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any " +
                    "/home/deploy/phantom/rasterizepdf.js " +" "+website+" " +previewLocation);
            proc.waitFor();
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/akshay/testme.png"));
            if(image!=null){

                if (image.getWidth() > image.getHeight()) {
                    image = Scalr.resize(image, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_HEIGHT, 250, 250);
                } else {
                    image = Scalr.resize(image, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH, 250, 250);
                }
                image = Scalr.crop(image, 250, 250);
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(previewLocation));
            }
            return identifier;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Any help would be nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. (a) I think the process of taking a screen shot is taking time. Is this code running on the same device as the chat screen? Why not use java.awt.Robot to take the screen shot ? or just save the text why do you need a screen shot?

(b) Is the system too busy/ Use on a SSD to see if faster?

(c) But curious as to the end application, is this part of a web app? How will your code run on the client systems? Or will you java agent be installed on all user systems that monitors the web page and takes screen shots? Then why use a web page, use a java app to chat, and parse the text as typed.

2. Parsing the text. What if user types/ pastes a long message? Are you parsing everything once or on change? Think of ways to improve that if it seems to be a problem. Ignore if not the immediate issue now.
   Also if the msg is too long the parsing can take a lot of time. maybe process after every key press or change event (if paste) keep local js copy of previous text to get diff?

Comment: Yes, process of screenshot is taking a lot of time, even on faster network on localhost. That's what I don't understand. As it's a chat application, we want to show preview of the website. I didn't understood your 2nd point. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the OS, how busy the system is, how fast the drive is (SSD will be much faster).

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer without context, how long is each method taking, what is your goal ... i just wrote a few generic things in my answer, might help you find a soltion